# Selenium webdriver- Not able to click on option which becomes visible on hover

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here i'm using linkedin for the learning purpose & want to perform the action on Edit profile=> work experience=> Add position. Here "Add position" button comes under work experience which becomes visible on hovering to that specific area. Look at my code,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("login-email")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("login email")).sendKeys("email id");
driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Profile")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

/* To scroll the page down */

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

/* To hover mouse on required option*/

```
Actions hover=new Actions(driver);
hover.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('background-experience')/div[1]/div/button[1]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('background-experience')/div[1]/div/button[1]")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

/* To Edit company name */

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('companyName-positionCompany-position-editPositionForm')")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('companyName-positionCompany-position-editPositionForm')")).sendKeys("testing company");
```

This is so on continued to edit work details but when i execute, it stops the page at work experience & not able to click on add position button to edit work.
It gives error on "edit company" code line. Can anyone help me to perform the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Hover
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement menuHoverLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='background-experience']/div[1]/div/button[1]"));
actions.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink);
actions.Build().Perform();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='background-experience']/div[1]/div/button[1]")).Click();
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you modifed the code so that can help me to use in better way? It's found that you added "contains" in xpath & actions.build().perform();

Comment: Sorry for the contains (I copy it from my working code and didn't delete it) the code should work now

Comment: The first part just hover the menu and the second click on it (check if this menu is in the same frame you use if now switch to it).

Comment: For the editing company use By.id:
driver.findElement(By.Id("companyName-positionCompany-position-editPositionForm")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.Id("companyName-positionCompany-position-editPositionForm")).sendKeys("testing company");

Comment: Note that after multiple trials I modified the code a bit by changing pixel value for scrolling the page down from  jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");  to  jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", ""); And surprisingly it works!!